# Ext JS 4: Rich Text or HTML Text Editor in Sencha Ext JS Framework

Tags: .net, extjs, html-editor, rich-text-editor

Does the Ext JS 4 framework provide a widget for rich text (or HTML) editing?  If not, let me know your recommendation about any tools (ie: jQuery, YUI, etc..) that you have used that provide this functionality. I used the Telerik RadControls editor before, but it's not free and I'm looking for a free tool. I'd like a JavaScript HTML editor if possible.

My server code is written in .NET, but I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do have HTML editor component: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor

Comment: Ah!  Thanks.  I was expecting to find it on their samples page.